# What is a good way to use Regex effectively for file names?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, file, if-statement

I have some Files on my Computer. Examples :

1. [Group] Name Year ' [Class2B] Hans 2011
2. Group_Name_Year ' Class2B_Hans_2011'
3. Name-Year-Theme 'Hans-2011-Wikipedia'

These are word files from my students.

I want Regex to analyse these Filenames and try different pattern to get all information out of the filename. After that i want to collect these and put ihm into a List<> for example.

Currently i am working with this kind of code.

```
public static string? GetGroup(string filename)
{
    if (fileName == null)
                return null;

                if (fileName.Contains("Class2B") || ("Class 2B"))
                {
                    string result = "2B";
                    return result.ToString();
                }
                else if (fileName.Contains("Class1A") || fileName.Contains("Class 1A") || fileName.Contains("1A"))
                {
                    string result = "1A";
                    return result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    string result = "Default";
                    return result.ToString();
                }
}
```

The problem with Regex is that filenames can be very(!) different from each other. I have the time to make like 50 Patterns. But i need some Sample Code that i can check all the pattern and if a pattern matches without losing any important vars. Some files don't contain group infos. some have underlines for spaces. some have dots.

PPS: I have tried Neural Network to help me analyse Filenames. But i'am not skilled enough.

I hope some of you could help me out.

I did try Regex but i am not finding an effective solution. I did try if-statements and also Neural Network.

Regex always making good progess with one example like [Group]Fischer-2011 but when i check Hans-Wikipedia-2012 it was getting errors. Cause of the different filenames.

At least all the filenames have consisdens "Name" and Date(4 digits).

if statements are my current option cause they search deeper and are flexible.
problem is when names or themes getting split like Hans-Klaus-Energy-Class2B-2011.

Comment: `string result = "2B";  return result.ToString();` could be shortened to just `return "2B";` There is no need to store the parameter, or to call ToString on it

Comment: Some AI tooling might indeed help here, but I don't know one for this specific use case. You might be better of renaming all the files to a consistent scheme manually or with tool support, so you can do a simplified name analysis.

Comment: Just divide the text, instead of using a _regex_.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Tell me some examples. Microsofts ML'Net kinda difficult to learn.

Answer (score 2):

To get the group you could use a regex like

```
(Class[._\-\s]?([0-9][A-Z]))
```

I.e. "Class" followed by zero or one separators, followed by a number and a letter. Using one capture group to capture the entire "Class 2B", and one to just get the "2B"-part.

To find the year you could use something like `(20[0-9][0-9])`, assuming all years are between 1999 and 2099.

The name and theme may be difficult to extract unless you have a list, or they appear in a consistent order.

To deal with different separators you could try to normalize the strings by replacing all possible separators with a single one.

You could also remove everything you have identified, like group and year, from the string, and then split it into parts using one or more separators, and use the order to identify everything else.

For example, given "Class_2A Hans-Wikipedia-2012", find the class and year with regexes and remove them -> " Hans-Wikipedia-". Split into parts, removing empty entries -> "Hans", "Wikipedia". Presumably the first one is the name, and the second the theme.

Or you could hire a student to manually fix existing submissions, and require future submissions to follow a specified format, automatically verified with a regex.

Comment: ` To deal with different separators you could try to normalize the
 strings by replacing all possible separators with a single one.`

Thanks. This is a way i didn't think about earlier.
Will try.

Answer (score 0):

From the examples you provided, I can say that you can easily find group and year using the following regex:
`((\[?Class(?<Group>\d[a-zA-Z])\]?)|(?<Year>\d{4})|(\w+)|([ _\-.]))+`

- `(\[?Class(?<Group>\d[a-zA-Z])\]?)` part matches the word `Class`, surrounded by `[]` or not, followed by a digit and a letter. Digit and letter are in a group named `Group` and can be received with `Regex.GroupNumberFromName(String)` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.groupnumberfromname?view=net-8.0)
- `(?<Year>\d{4})` part matches a year in a named group `Year`
- `(\w+)` part matches any word, it could be student name or a theme, can't really advice you on how to distinguish them
- `([ _\-.])` matches a delimiter

All the parts can come in any order in a file name. The regex above matches all the examples you provided and gives you the ability to get group and year info if they are present.